# Minimum floor fan CFM to push air from basement to cool down the main floor

Tags: ventilation

Temperature in the basement of my home is consistently 6-7 degrees lower than in the main floor.  I would like to circulate cold air from the basement to the main floor to cool it down during hot days using a powerful floor fan and furnace fan. Realising that that there is a lot of unknowns, how do I *roughly* estimate the minimum floor fan CFM required to lower the temperature of the main floor?

Basement size: 800 sq feet.

Main floor size: 800 sq feet.

Comment: do be aware that if you start circulating air from your basement with the upstairs you will quickly lose that difference, depending on how well insulated your basement is from the soil.

Comment: If you have a hot air furnace, simply put the fan on (with the heat off). Do understand that whatever power your fans take is also heating the air while moving it. As such, efficient fans are better than merely powerful ones.

Comment: @Ecnerwal how do I know if a fan is efficient?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I think about also.

You would need two fans(probably) one to push cold air up, and one to push warm air down.

While it seems like it might work to cool the upstairs, I think it would only work for a couple of hours a day, need the temperatures up and down equalize.

Cool air sinks and warm air rises, is why basements are usually much cooler than upstairs.

Once you start mixing you lose the difference.

If like me you do not need/want A/C that much(a couple days a year)  It might work for a bit, to cool down the house near evening.

Comment: I agree and you'd need two opening, most basements only have one opening to the first floor so now you're cutting another one.

Comment: @JACK  That is what chainsaws are for.

Comment: I think I'll stick with a circular saw and finish off with a saber saw... In reality though, the OP would have to do a lot of planning  for minimal benefits.

Comment: Might be easier to set up a bed down there.  Will get to sleep in cooler air for longer time.

Comment: I appreciate the sense of humour, but the question was not meant to be that way. If you push cold air up, it will get replaced by warm air coming from ventilation ducts. I understand that this is not in any way, shape or form a replacement of AC, but if I could lower the air temperature upstairs (compared to its "normal state"), the goal would be achieved.

Comment: @slava-kohut   If you have centre air furnace can try by opening the furnace fan door and turning on the furnace fan.  It should bring downstairs cool air up, without having to add extra fans or openings.  If it works well, then you can think about adding more fans.

Comment: Instead of trying to mix the air, which might not last that long, I think it would better try to move important(to you) cool times downstairs.  The cool basement/downstairs air will stay cooler for days/weeks, instead of for a few cooler hours upstairs.